# How to do exception handling in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a little console application that will read in excel data with the help of ExcelDataReader. The code for the console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeData data = new SomeData(@"C:\SC.xlsx", "somedata_2014");
        IEnumerable<SomeType> someTypes = someData.GetData();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Please don't worry about the naming of the variables; this is for a company and I don't want  use anything company related. Next up is the SomeData class:

```
public class SomeData
{
    private string path;
    private string worksheetName;

    public SomeData(string path, string worksheetName)
    {
        this.path = path;
        this.worksheetName = worksheetName;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SomeType> GetData(bool isFirstRowAsColumnNames = true)
    {
        var excelData = new ExcelData(path);

        try
        {
            var ad = excelData.GetData(worksheetName, isFirstRowAsColumnNames);

            return ad.Select(dataRow => new SomeType()
            {
                Gemeente = dataRow["LivingPlace"].ToString(),
                Geslacht = dataRow["Outdoors"].ToString(),
                Woonplaats = dataRow["WellHellYesOrNo"].ToString()
            }).ToList();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the ExcelData class that is a level lower than the SomeData class:

```
public class ExcelData
{
    private string path;

    public ExcelData(string path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    private IExcelDataReader GetExcelDataReader()
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                IExcelDataReader dataReader = null;

                if (path.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    dataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fileStream);
                }

                if (path.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    dataReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fileStream);
                }

                return dataReader;
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataRow> GetData(string sheet, bool isFirstRowAsColumnNames = true)
    {
        var reader = GetExcelDataReader();
        reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = isFirstRowAsColumnNames;
        var workSheet = reader.AsDataSet().Tables[sheet];
        var rows = from DataRow row in workSheet.Rows select row;

        return rows;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do, is that when something goes wrong with e.g. opening an excel file, I would like it to throw an exception, and I would like it to bubble up so that I can write it out at the top level.

The same goes for the GetData method of the SomeData class; at the moment that I want to read the data for a certain column and something goes wrong, I would like for it to throw an exception that bubbles up so once again I can write it out at the top level.

I'm just looking for the best way to do this.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What does "if something goes wrong" mean? Exceptions will always bubble up until they're caught, so all you have to do is use a try/catch in `Main`... beyond that it's not really clear what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Don't catch and throw. There's no point. You exceptions will bubble up anyway, so unless you are going to do something with the exception (for example, log the error), you don't need to catch and immediately rethrow. Also, consider creating a custom attribute for your code so that you can add whatever other properties you might think are relevant and might help in debugging or understanding the error.

Comment: @AntP Many things can go wrong that is out my hands when someone uploads a (in this specific case excel file) file. Stuff could also not be correct in the file. I want to check for those errors and the subsequent errors that will be thrown.

Comment: Well, if stuff isn't right in the file, then you need to write code to validate those conditions *specifically* and then throw exceptions. Unfortunately there's no magic button that will evaluate all possible failure cases for you; that's your job as a programmer. Define custom exception classes if you need to be able to handle those exceptions specifically. If you're talking about things that will already throw exceptions, then you just need to catch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions "bubble" by default; there's no point in rethrowing an exception without doing anything, that's just wasted code and CPU. In fact, that's pretty much the whole modus operandi of exceptions - whatever happens, wherever it happens, it will bubble up to the first guy ready to handle it. So you only need the `try { ... } catch (WhateverException ex) { ... }` at the point where you're actually ready to handle it.

Any exceptions that aren't handled at all will simply kill your application (although do note that certain frameworks like Winforms will give you an option to e.g. try and continue - in general, though, you should handle all those yourself anyway, it's just the final safety net).

Comment: Right, so basically in my main I would have the try, and possibly multiple catch blocks, for the things that could go wrong

Comment: @user3488442 Yes. Do note that there's a hierarchical tree of exceptions, so if you don't actually have different code to handle different exceptions, it might be worth it to just have a `catch (Exception ex)` to handle all exceptions at once. This is often used by the top-level exception handling code ("catch everything, log it down, and then either warn the user or rethrow again").

Answer (score 1):

The best way to catch exceptions at "higher" levels would be to just not catch them at all at "lower" levels. They'll automatically bubble up and you can catch / handle them at whatever point you deem appropriate.

There's no reason for code like this, since the only thing you're doing is re-throwing the exception.

```
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    throw;
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Code like this is fine, since you're doing something with the exception before re-throwing it. For example, you might log an exception before re-throwing it so the calling method can catch it and handle it too (such as displaying an error to the user).

```
catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
    throw;
}
```

If you can handle and fix an issue at the lower levels, catch the exception there and fix the issue. If you want all exceptions to bubble up to the top where you can alert the user, then remove all your try / catch blocks and catch only in `Main`:

```
try
{
    SomeData data = new SomeData(@"C:\SC.xlsx", "somedata_2014");
    IEnumerable<SomeType> someTypes = someData.GetData();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: As I commented to someone else in this thread, I probably should remove these try/catch ones and put them at the entry point of my program, with multiple catch blocks..

Comment: I guess so, although (and I'm not sure if it is correct or not), I would like to have specific catches in place of the general Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't catch excpetions in every method - you should only ever catch exceptions if you can do something with it (handle it (i.e. not rethrow it), add some important contextual information or if it is important for logging purposes)

So the way you have in mind is good, either let it bubble upop to the gui and or, if you can handle / add information you could also catch it in the data class but I wouldn`t catch it in every class I use

Of course the decision depends also on which of youur parts are reused by other apps / components.

One mor thing is exception chaining: low level exception (for example "divide by zero") are reraised as a new exception like "data exception".. depends on your application model

Answer (score -2):

I guess what you are trying to do is make the error bubble up to the top level so you can see where it was thrown on several levels. Am I correct?
Anyway, you do not need to catch/throw statement but instead define a method
as throwable like

```
public IEnumerable<SomeType> GetData(bool isFirstRowAsColumnNames = true) throws Exception
```

In this case if an error occurs in GetData, it will bubble upwards
You can also defined what kind of expression should be thrown or define multiple exception that can be thrown

Comment: Ops, sorry. Am new here and did not register the C# tag

Comment: public void TestMethod() throws Exception 
is Java syntax for compiler optimization but I do not know of any C# equivalent

Comment: Exactly, and there is no equivalent for C#, as far as I know